# How to remove all symbols ,numbers and spaces from string?

Tags: python, regex

i have string like this

```
603 - CELLULITIS W/O MCC
```

i want to convert it to

```
CELLULITISWOMCC
```

in python using regex
my previous attempts

```
 s= re.sub(r"(\b|\s+\-?|^\-?)(\d+\s[-]\s|\d*\.\d+)\b","",s)
```

which lead me to this 
**CELLULITIS W/O MCC**

Comment: Did you try something? Perhaps include that in the question if you have.

Comment: Make a regex for anything that is not a letter and replace it with an empty string. Have you used regex yet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a coding service.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: On-topic hint: `[^A-Z]` matches any character which is _not_ a letter. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to remove non capital alphabet characters, a negation regex would work much better than a positive regex. Search for characters that are not capital alphabets and replace with empty string.

You may try like so:

```
import re

s1 = "603 - CELLULITIS W/O MCC "
s2 = re.sub(r'[^A-Z]+', r'', s1)
print s2
```

Output:

```
CELLULITISWOMCC
```

Regex:

`[^A-Z]+` - Match 1 or more characters which are not from `A` to `Z`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/OCNztP/1